# Python: Write 3 dimensional array to CSV file

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I am trying to write a program that takes in data from a JSON file, puts it into arrays, and then writes the arrays into a CSV file for human-readability. I am already parsing the JSON file and the array comes out looking like this:

```
sensorTest = [[[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9],
               [10, 11, 12]],
              [[13, 14, 15],
               [16, 17, 18],
               [19, 20, 21],
               [22, 23, 24]]]
```

I want this to be written to a CSV file so that the elements of each list are placed in their own column like this: [The desired CSV output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPzGP.png)

Instead, out of everything I have tried, I keep getting something that essentially just places all the array elements in the first column like this: [Bad output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0HNu.png)

I'll attach my code below.

```
import json
import csv
from os import walk
from os import path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == "__main__":
sensorBoard = [0, 1]
    with open("./Data/sensorData.csv", "w", encoding='utf8', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvfile.write("C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8\n")
        hrd = csv.writer(csvfile)   # hrd is human-readable data
        for board in sensorBoard:  # loop through element number of lists
            print(board)
            print(sensorTest[board])
            # print(sensorTest[board][0])
            # print(sensorTest[board][1])
            for channelIndex, channelVals in enumerate(sensorTest[board]):  # this grabs the set of values for the channel
                print(sensorTest[board][channelIndex])
                # hrd.writerow([str(sensorTest[board][channelIndex])])
                for valIndex, val in enumerate(sensorTest[board][channelIndex]):
                    hrd.writerow([str(val)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Python do more of the work for you:

```
data = sensorTest[0]+sensorTest[1]
with open("output.csv", "w", encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    hrd = csv.writer(csvfile)
    hrd.writerow(["C%d"%d for d in range(1,1+len(data))])
    for r in zip(*data):
        hrd.writerow(r)
```

Comment: holy cow you're a godsend. is there a way to do it so that it doesn't skip a row between the values?

Comment: What do you mean by "skip a row between the values"?  Maybe try specifying `newline` in `open`?

Comment: When I open the csv file in excel it looks like each array element skips a row: https://imgur.com/a/pfOc1R3. Edit: looks like adding newline='' to open fixed it. Thanks again!

Comment: Using `newline="\n"` worked for me.